# Hide youtube player controls dynamically

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

i have created player using below code and initially i have set controls value 1 and

```
 ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    height: '400',
    width: '100%',

    playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 0,
        'controls': 1,
        'frameborder': 0,
        'modestbranding': 1,
        'rel': 0,
        'showinfo': 0
    },
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
});
```

now i want to hide control dynamically. so for that i have tried player.setOption method but i unable to do it with that so anyone can  help me??

Comment: Do you found any solution...?

Comment: I am also interested, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I hadn't found any solution. I hide from beginning and created custom as per my requirement like https://lingojingo.com/Course/774/Lessons/3245/none-en/Fun-with-Numbers--Counting-50-100/Video--1-100/0